# Building shared library for lua in Linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to create my own C module that is then accessed with Lua. Therefore I am doing [this](http://www.playwithlua.com/?p=49) tutorial. When the C code is built to a shared library in the tutorial they use the command

```
gcc -shared -o kb.so kb.c -undefined dynamic_lookup -lncurses
```

for MAC OS.

I am using Ubuntu and I somehow can't figure out what the equivalent command is for the compiler on Linux. Especially the dynamic_lookup option that tells the compiler to look for all libs it can't find at runtime(in this case lua libraries).

So can anyone tell me the equivalent command for the Linux compiler?

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using on Mac and Ubuntu? (check using `gcc --version`)

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4